# Is there a way to successfully loop an Angular service call

Tags: json, angular, for-loop

How can I successfully run the following code?

```
onSubmit() {

    let pdfData = [
      {
        field_name: 'data.Date',
        value: this.freshDeskData.date,
        placeholder: '',
        page_no: 1,
      },
      {
        field_name: 'data.Fullname',
        value: "Bob Jones",
        placeholder: '',
        page_no: 1,
      },
    ];

     for(let i=0;i<pdfData.length;i++){
       this.signHub.addPDFInfo(pdfData[i]).subscribe((data) => {
         this.responseData = data[i]
       });
    }
  }
```

Add PDF Service:

```
 addPDFInfo(pdfInfo): Observable<PDFInfo> {
    return this.http.put<PDFInfo>(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/api/workflow/add-text-block?package_ID=${this.package_ID.data.package_id}&current_Document_ID=${this.current_Document_ID.data.documentid}`,
      pdfInfo
    );
```

}

The service is meant to loop through the JSON object and POST the information on the selected item to populate the related field on a PDF document. However, only one field is populated via the loop. The other remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using the RxJs `merge`-operator, eg.:

```js
onSubmit() {

    let pdfData = [
      {
        field_name: 'data.Date',
        value: this.freshDeskData.date,
        placeholder: '',
        page_no: 1,
      },
      {
        field_name: 'data.Fullname',
        value: "Bob Jones",
        placeholder: '',
        page_no: 1,
      },
    ];

     const requests = [];
     for(let i=0;i<pdfData.length;i++){
       requests.push(this.signHub.addPDFInfo(pdfData[i]));
     }
     merge(...requests).subscribe((data) => {
         this.responseData = data[i]
       })
  }
```

granted you'd need to combine the results of each "next result" (that you're currently assigning to `this.responseData`). A candidate to solve that issue could be the `reduce`-operator

But, it's difficult to give a precise answer, without having knowledge about more of your codebase.

Comment: What would be `i` in `data[i]` here? TBH the question isn't clear about either.

Comment: Oooopsie, I think I copy/pasted too much. Yeah, that was the part about me suggesting looking into using the `reduce`-operator. I only see one of two actions, reducing the multiple responses into one, or appending them to an array / object-structure.